# How to refresh navbar so that latest title is displayed?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationbar, page-title

In my implementation, I will change the title of the page after triggering some method

```
//In viewdidload of my view controller which resides in a navigation controller
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.title = @"Title A";
}


-(void)changeTitle
{
    self.title = @"Title B";
}
```

In the above example, after I trigger the 'changeTitle' method, I do not see my viewcontroller's title change immediately. In fact I need to push another viewcontroller onto the stack and subsequently press 'back' before I see the change to "title B".

Is there any way to refresh the navbar's title at the point where I change title?

Comment: Try `[self.view setNeedsLayout];`

Comment: Hmmm tried, but still the same, title did not change. I tried [self.navigationController.view setNeedLayout] to no avail as well

Comment: Here must be something else wrong, cause I do this all the time. I know this is not much of a help, but maybe you could display more context, since the problem seem to be deeper.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for:

UrNavController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"bkjasdkahsdflkjadf";

You can reset it after you press a button.

You may also assign some other objects to that topitem like a segmentcontrol, or uilabel.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refresh the previous viewController's title then use

```
self.parent?.title = "Some Title"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Objective-C**

```
[self.navigationItem setTitle:@"XYZ"];
```

**Swift 4.2**

```
self.navigationItem.title = "XYZ"
```